# Generate random number in python, such that the likelihood of a number being generated is inversely proportionate to it's value

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a pseudo random number from 1 to *n* in python, but the likelihood of a number being generated should be lesser the higher the number is.
So,
1 will be the most likely outcome of this random function
2 will be half as likely as 1
3 will be one-third as likely as 1
4 will be one-fourth as likely as 1
...
*k* will be 1/*k* as likely as 1.

So if there's a 1/10 chance the outcome will be 1, the chance for 2 will be 1/20, 3: 1/30, *k*: 1/10*k*.

I don't want to make a list and choose a random value or any such inaccurate hacks so don't suggest that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you accept an accurate hack?

```
random.choices(range(1,n+1),[1/k for k in range(1,n+1)])
```

works. Furthermore it has an optional parameter `k` which lets you generate as many random numbers as you need.

Comment: omg its perfect tysm

Answer (score 0):

The Scipy package can generate random reciprocals as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.reciprocal.html)

In this example, we create a single random value from the range N = 1 - 10:

```
from scipy.stats import reciprocal
>>> r = reciprocal.rvs(1, 10, size=1)
>> r
array([ 3.83178852])
```

The returned value is an array of `size` elements.